# Analyzing Bert Output for Sequence Classification

Tags: text-classification, bert-language-model

Can anyone help me understand the output of BERT in the last hidden layer for sequence classification?  I am doing some testing with a huggingface model for sequence classification and accessing the output as follows:

```
sequence = "this coffee tastes bad"
tok_sequence = tokenizer(sequence)

output = model(**tok_sequence)       # model inference
output[1][0]                         # accessed by setting config.output_hidden_states = True
output[1][0].shape                   # --> (1, 7, 768) --> | CLS | this | coffee | taste | ##s | bad | SEP |
```

In the string "this coffee tastes bad," I am basically taking the outputs of the last hidden layer, which in this case has shape (1, 7, 768), [CLS] + 5 word tokens + [SEP], and looping through each token summing up their values (768) and computing the average. The resulting totals are outputted in the below chart image.

[Output of BERT model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34KAb.png)

[Additional BERT output example - longer sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHBMn.png)

Any help interpreting would be helpful.  The direction I am looking to go with this is extracting words with the most meaning or that influenced the output sentiment most.  In looking at the output, especially the second example, it appears the positive values are less important words, and the negative values are influential words.  This seems to hold true for most output examples.  However, i may be off in my understanding of this.

Any other suggested methods would also be helpful for text classification.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by analyze? What would like you to know about the embeddings? You might find this tool useful: https://github.com/pair-code/lit/

Comment: By analyze, i mean understand the output of the last hidden layer, specifically the values associated with each token, as shown in the attached images.  Thanks for the reference to lit, i will check it out as well.